# Effect of solenoid on iron core in ac and dc circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current

If i have 2 insulated coils and i wrap each one of them on a iron core (i have 2 seperate ciruits) if i add a dc source “battery” in the first circuit and an ac source in the second circuit would there be any difference in the heating effect on the iron cores? Or would there be no heating effect at all?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the AC source would result in heating in the iron core. The iron core heating is due to eddy currents that can only be induced by an AC current in the coil. DC coil currents can result in DC magnetic flux, but cannot induce an eddy current in the core.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!